# How can I send a message to the currently selected table cell after it has moved off-screen?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Here’s my scenario:

I’m showing a `UITableViewController` in a `UINavigationController`, and I’m drawing the cells myself in a subclass. In order to keep the cells looking as close to possible like native cells, I have a flag that indicates whether it is in a transitional state or not, in order to prevent the text color from visibly flashing when the user moves back up the stack from a detail view to the table view.

Currently, I set my transitioning flag in `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // (stuff for pushing the detail view on to the navigation stack)

    ((MyCustomTableViewCell *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath]).transitioning = YES;
}
```

This works rather well, with one caveat: Immediately before the list animates off-screen, the transition is clearly visible to anyone looking for it, as the cell text changes to black (on blue) from white (on blue.)

**My question:** Is there any way to get the currently selected cell from the table view, *after* it has transitioned off-screen, and send it a message? (assuming it isn’t being deallocated, simply unloaded)

Or am I simply going about this whole thing the wrong way?

(For anyone considering saying that nobody will notice it, keep in mind that it’s acceptable to me the way that it is, I’m simply wondering if there’s a way for me to make it better. Good iOS applications are all about the little things.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView does not keep a publicly-accessible list of all the cells in the table.
In order to access all the cells (including ones out of the screen) you need to maintain a separate array of the cells you generate.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController 
{
   NSMutableArray* tableCells;
}



@implementation MyViewController

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableCells == nil)
      tableCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UITableViewCell* cell;
    if (indexPath.row < [tableCells count])
    {
        // Return a cell from the cached list
        cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        // Create a new cell
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];  

        // Customize and fill the cell with content anyway you wish
        // ...
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Now that you have a list of all the cells in the table, you can send them any message, anytime you want.

Comment: Um… yes it does. UITableView-cellForRowAtIndexPath: will return a reference to any particular cell you like. But, your answer does have some merit, in that it suggests saving a reference to the cell in question and passing it elsewhere for message sending. I’ll give that a try.

Comment: PS: I pray to $DEITY that you have never used this code. It’s so… wrong. Have you ever looked at Apple’s template for navigation-based applications, or any that use a UITableViewController?

Comment: @abrahamvegh: As I said in my response, to my knowledge, UITableView does not keep a reference to all the cells in the table - only the visible ones. That's what the delegate cellForRowAtIndexPath is for: to allow you to make your own management of the cells (using dequeue is just a choice, not an obligation). The UITableView-cellForRowAtIndexPath will return nil if your cell is outside the visible area (it's in the documentation). This comes to support the idea that UITableView does not store a reference to all cells.

Comment: Considering my above comment, the only solution for your problem (access any cell anytime) is to store the entire list of cells in your application. UITableView does not do this for you, so you're kind of forced to do it.

Comment: That does make sense, but it ignores the fact that my question asks specifically about a cell that has just been selected, which therefore guarantees that it is visible, which guarantees that I have at least two `UITableView`-built-in ways to access a reference to it (`-visibleCells` and `-indexPathForSelectedRow`.) I’m fairly certain I made no indication about wanting to access any cell at any time, although I do appreciate the effort toward that cause.

Comment: Regarding the “choice” of using dequeue: On any table larger than a few cells, the performance implications of **not** using dequeue should be unacceptable to any production implmentation.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your question correctly. This is what i've read from your post: "My question: Is there any way to get the currently selected cell from the table view, after it has transitioned off-screen, and send it a message?". 
Anyway, about using dequeue. I still think it's a choice. If it's good  to ignore it depends on the application and the data displayed.
And performance-wise I think not using dequeue is faster: you don't have to recreate/refill the cells with new content - they are already created. It eats a lot of memory however.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "prevent the text color from visibly flashing"? By default iOS table cells don't appear to do that, at least in an unpleasant way. Perhaps you can revisit your UITableViewCell implementation and determine if you are incorrectly handling -setSelected:animated: and -setHighlighted:animated

Comment: I’m drawing my cell myself using CoreGraphics. If you want to use the built-in blue highlight color (which, btw, is not actually a color, but an image), then doing your drawing with CG will cause the text color to flash from white to blank and then back to black when the cell is deselected, unless you change the text color back to black before the cell deselection is animated.